# Why is there no relative pronoun in "Collen described the accident she had during her winter holidays."?

Tags: relative-pronouns

I'm studying now an English book on German with the following term:

> *Collen described the accident she had during her winter holidays.*

I know it's an expanded attribute as the second part of the sentence. But why is there no relative pronoun like which or that?

Comment: "That" is optional except where 'gap' is subject, when it is obligatory.In your example, it is object of "had", ("Collen described the accident she had ___ during her winter holidays") and hence is optional. Note that "that" is a subordinator, not a relative pronoun, and the relative clause is a post-head modifier not an attributive one.

Comment: It's pretty much the same as the "optional subordinator" that OP himself didn't include in his own text: *I know [**that**] it's an expanded attribute...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's not needed. The relative pronoun can be omitted if it refers to an object of a verb. In this case, it refers to the object of verb "had".

> Collen described the accident (which) she had <s>which (=the accident)</s> during her winter holidays.